# Cascading / Hadoop: GroupBy / Reducer Based on Job Size

Tags: hadoop, cascading

Use case: After every record goes through an `Each` pipe, they'll be processed in batches of 200. It doesn't matter how they're grouped or ordered; aggregating records as groups of size 200 is sufficient.

Was thinking about the `Each` pipe emitting result and a `Key`, which acts as `groupFields` in `GroupBy`.  Then the `GroupBy` will emit groups of size 200 that I can process using `Every`. However, I won't know how many records there are up front, thus I'm stuck in designing a function to generate the `Key`.